# Is there a way to extract data from FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter

Since you can only return widgets in FutureBuilder I was wondering if there is a way to extract data from those widgets to modify it?

For example, is there a way to get to the "snapshot.data.value" here?

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
  return Text("${snapshot.data.value}");
} else if (snapshot.hasError) {
  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
}
```

Here is my parent widget from which im trying to get `snapshot.data.value`:

```
                  Container(
                    child: FirstWidget(),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: SecondWidget(),
                  ),
```

Here is my child widget that returns following FutureBuilder:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Api>(
      future: _apivalue,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          Test(er: snapshot.data.er);
          return Text("${snapshot.data.value}");
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return Text('');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Question is not clear but what i understand from your question is that you want to use the FutureBuilder data out side the widget. You can do that by storing the data inside a variable

```
var data; // Defined inside the state of widget as a local variable

if (snapshot.hasData) {
  data = snapshot.data;
  return Text("${snapshot.data.value}");
} else if (snapshot.hasError) {
  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
}
```

Comment: Not exacttly. I have a child widget which returns FutureBuilder, then in parent widget I call a child widget with something like this: Container(ChildWidget()). Here, I dont have access to snapshot.data.value, only to the Widget Text. And since my parent widget has multiple FutureBuilder I was trying to find a way to get that values to modify them.

Comment: Create a class that can store that data which mixin with ChangeNotifier class to provide value to a widget using provider package you can use that value any where in whole app

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering maybe there is an easier solution, will try to get into provider now.

Comment: easier solution is to simply await on that future you are using in FutureBuilder If you provide more code i will make it work for you mask TODO's in code

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it on my own